# Wordpress noob needs help getting started

Tags: wordpress

My question is so stupid and maybe that's why I can't find an answer for it, not even reading the wordpress documentation. But I'm really lost here. I have in front of me full access to a server (FTP) and also to its wordpress admin dashboard.

And I cannot find the files of the site, for example www.mydomain.com/members

Where is members? I can't find it, when I access the server I see the folders wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, etc... I see an index.php, but I don't see anything related to the pages I'm looking for.

Can you please provide me some insight on this?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is a web application.  The files and folders that you are looking at comprise Wordpress.  What you do not see is the page content that is displayed on the website.  That information is stored in a database on the server.  To edit that information you need to do it through Wordpress.  When a page is requested, Wordpress dynamically looks up the page contents that you requested from the database, assembles it into the theme that you have chose and sends it to you as a complete web page.

Comment: I don't want to edit the content, I want to edit the page where the information is 'assembled' like you said :) Where are these pages? Please note that I said Wordpress noob, not PHP/MySQL noob.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend.  That content is generally part of the theme, although you have to be careful because Wordpress can pull content of various types from the database, not just postings.  The themes are stored in the wp-content folder under themese.  There is a folder there for each theme.  Use the Wordpress admin to identify which theme you are using.  You can even do some basic theme editing from WP admin, but it's not suitable for anything but minor tweeks.

Comment: Most themes are somewhat self-documenting, but if you don't have much experience with the arcane WordPress theme structure and the purpose of all the various files included in it you should take a look at this page.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thank you :) That's the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

`www.mydomain.com/members` is a URL rewrite to make the URL easier to read.

I think it routes `www.mydomain.com/members` to `www.mydomain.com/index.php?action=members`, so that explains why only `index.php` is visible.

Basically, when a request goes to `www.mydomain.com/members`, it's actually going to `www.mydomain.com/index.php?action=members`. It just looks prettier.